# How to make Codeception work with Symfony 3 directory structure

Tags: upgrade, codeception, symfony

I recently upgraded my Symfony project to version 2.8 and then adopted the Symfony 3 directory structure. Now when I run Codeception it gives me the following error message:

> The annotation "@Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Entity" in class Acme\SiteBundle\Entity\Acme\User does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded."

So Doctrine annotations are not autoloaded. I know Symfony 3 made some changes concerning autoloading. How does this affect Codeception, what needs to be tweaked in order for it to work correctly?

Comment: Haven't upgrade yet, but have you seen the new config property for `var` yet? See [codeception Symfony3 directory structure](http://codeception.com/docs/modules/Symfony2#Symfony-3x-Directory-Structure) . I would guess that the bootstrap may be located there (which I think includes the autoload).

Comment: I do have the `var_path: 'var'` setting in my config file (Codeception complaints and won't work if it's not set). And yes the bootstrap file is in the `/var` folder but I'm not sure it includes the autoload... Anyway, without including it manually myself (see my answer), there's no autoloading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved it by requiring Symfony's autoload script in my suites' `_bootstrap` files.

```php
// tests/acceptance/_bootstrap.php
require __DIR__ . '/../../app/autoload.php';
```

I don't think it is a long term solution, but in the meantime, it works.